# What is the life cycle of a .net application

Tags: c#, .net

Having a simple .net .exe application. What is it's life cycle once executed. My understanding is that the following occurs:

```
> 1. OS loads exe assemblies into memory
> 2. OS checks if it is in fact .net assembly
> 3. mscoree.dll loads, and loads CLR
> 4. CLR takes over and loads external dlls, GC stuff, memory management etc.
> 5. CLR creates app domain where exe assemblies are loaded
> 6. exe is started
```

Given the above is correct (please feel free to elaborate), I'm interested in the last step, when the CLR loads assemblies.

1. How many stacks, heaps, threads are created?. Is the thread created and that executes the code within the executable?
2. What is the size of the initial memory allocated?, who allocates the memory (OS or CLR?)
3. How does it know how much memory is initially needed?
4. If more memory is needed when the exe runs, who decides how much and when to allocate this memory?
5. What happens when you close the exe?, does the CLR run any GC right before unloading the App Domain? (closing exe), or does the OS?

Comment: Just buy the book "CLR via C#" or read the blog series "CLR Inside Out". This is way too broad to properly answer, and I'm quite certain each of your questions has been answered before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the process itself is a bit more complicated than you wrote. Some of the steps includes a bit more than one may think - for example, step 1 and how PE loaded (and mscoree.dll itself loaded) include inner-steps inside.

But, I'll try to answer your questions. Just notice that your questions are kinda big, so I tried to answer them briefly. But, if you really interested in that I highly recommend you to read the  **CLR via C#** (by Richter). He discusses the loading process in the first chapter, and has dedicated chapter for the garbage collector.

There are also some good MSDN articles about the fundamentals of the garbage collector that you may find interesting.

> How many stacks, heaps, threads are created?. Is the thread created and that executes the code within the executable?

Simple (empty) console application will have 3 threads: main thread, GC thread and finalizers thread. of course, each of the thread has it own stack (1MB each).

The number of heaps depends on the GC type you're using. If you're using Workstation GC (the default) there will be 1 managed heap (with 2 segments, one for "normal" objects and one is the large object heap segment).

If you're working with Server GC there will be 1 heap for each logical core available in the system (each one of the heaps with two segments).

> What is the size of the initial memory allocated?, who allocates the memory (OS or CLR?)

The initial memory consists of more than one element: there is 1MB stack for each thread, there is the size of the images that loaded in the process (which depends on your application of course), and there is the "dynamic" element of the size - the allocations you're making in your application, that cause the GC to increase the heap size, and the objects you're not using anymore that cleaned by the GC and may cause the GC to free memory.

> If more memory is needed when the exe runs, who decides how much and when to allocate this memory?

If you have a simple console application, that inside the Main you create instance of a new class. In that case, the "new" keyword (CIL "newobj" instruction) will make the CLR calculate the required amount of memory.

If there's enough memory in generation 0 (where newly created object are stored), there will be no additional memory allocation. If there isn't enough memory, the GC will kick in and will call VirtualAlloc to allocate memory for the object. The reference for the new created object, in that scenario, will be saved on stack.

Of course, where the reference are saved (stack, heap, processor register) and where objects are allocated (stacks/heap) can vary. Basically, that depends if we're talking about allocation of class or struct, and what's the context of the allocation (if it's inside method, as a field in other class, a field in struct etc.). It can also vary based on the platform.

> If more memory is needed when the exe runs, who decides how much and when to allocate this memory?

All the memory allocation for new objects created in your process is managed by the CLR itself (of course, the CLR use Windows API such as VirtualAlloc and VirtualFree, and windows managing the virtual memory itself).

When you use the "new" operator to create a new object that should be created in the managed heap, the CLR calculate the size required to allocate (the size of all the fields + a little overhead required for locking ob objects and know what type it is) and see if there's available space in the managed heap (in generation 0, the CLR always keeps a pointer to where new objects should be allocated). If so, it uses it. otherwise, if there's not enough memory a garbage collection begins, and sometimes (depends on the memory status after the gc process, and some other stuff) VirtualAlloc will be called by the CLR to allocate more memory for the process.

> What happens when you close the exe?, does the CLR run any GC right before unloading the App Domain? (closing exe), or does the OS?

The CLR run quick GC before unloading any app-domain. The purpose of this quick GC is to let the finalizes a chance to run. When closing the process, there is no need for the CLR to clean the memory, because the OS does that anyway.

Hope it helps.

Comment: #3. Suppose you have new Dictionary<K,T>() in the code, does the main thread, (CLR), account for that?, increases the size of the heap? what is the initial size of the heap-before reading new Dict line?

Comment: edited my answer, hope it answer it a bit more...

Comment: *If you're working with Server GC there will be 1 heap for each logical thread available in the system* I assume you meant a heap for each logical core.

Comment: Yuval, of course. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Good response. I am just curious when I read in depth responses like these, does this come from your memory, or did you have to pull out a book or some online resource to respond. I ask because, idk if I can ever get to a point in life where I can just talk like a book.

Comment: @eaglei22 the answer is based on previous knowledge that came from reading books (for example, CLR via C#), blog posts etc.  no magic involved :)

Comment: @Shahar looks like I will be picking up that book! :)  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 8):

> How many stacks, heaps, threads are created?

In the process, in which you application lives, there may be many threads. However, one of them would be the main thread of execution.

When a thread is created it is allocated a 1-MB stack.

> who allocates the memory (OS or CLR?)

As is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The common language runtime's garbage collector manages the allocation
>   and release of memory for an application

This is a significant difference between managed and un-managed programs. If you have programmed in either C or C++, you definitely know that this responsibility belongs to the developer and not to a garbage collector. It's a great power. But with great power comes great responsibility. You are responsible for finding (creating) the needed memory space. Then you allocate there your object and when you don't need it more, you have to release this memory. Any mistake that may done in the above process leads to memory leaks and even to the crash of your program. Let alone the difficulty of troubleshooting a bug like this.

On the other hand, in the world of managed programs (C#, Java, JavaScript, etc.) this responsibility belongs to a piece of the runtime that is called garbage collector. The garbage collector allocates the memory and decides, when it's the appropriate time to kick in and garbage the litters. This from it's own is a great convenience making the developer's life significantly easier. However it's a trade-off. A managed program can't hit the performance of a well structured un-managed program.

> What happens when you close the exe?, does the CLR run any GC right
>   before unloading the App Domain? (closing exe), or does the OS?

When you close an executable, one of the things that will be done, before the unloading of the application domain takes place, is a garbage collection, in order of any used resources to be released. Then the application domain would be unloaded. After this the CLR would be detached from the process's memory space and last the process would be killed.